# Can flour be made from breadcrumbs?

Tags: flour, chemistry, breadcrumbs

Can flour be made from breadcrumbs, or is flour → bread an irreversible chemical reaction?

<sup>I'm wondering if new bread can be made from ground stale bread (i.e., breadcrumbs).</sup>

Comment: You might be able to use it like flour in some specific applications— like as a thickener, or to dry the surface of something in a three part breading, but it can’t do everything that flour could

Answer (score 3):

You can use breadcrumbs to make food like dumplings or puddings, but you won't be able to use it as flour to make new bread. The cooking process is an irreversible one in this case.